# Adding a few missing shortcuts in Eclipse (from IntelliJ user)

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

My coworker keeps insisting that I make the switch from IntelliJ to Eclipse.  I'm considering relenting, mainly because the compile/deploy time it takes for my Android project seems to be considerably less in Eclipse than IntelliJ (I imagine Eclipse does some sort of incremental compilation, etc. that IntelliJ can't do for Android).

However, there are a few shortcuts that I feel are essential and I don't want to do without, and I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to do them in Eclipse (perhaps add via a plugin?):

- Ctrl-W (select word, and then expands selection to include statement,
  block, method, class... this should work in XML and other types of code as well)
- Ctrl-D (duplicate selection, if selection, or otherwise line)
- Ctrl-Shift-V, paste from history (pops up a list of recently copied text)
- Go to Symbol (searches through all methods, fields, etc in your project)

I'm sure there are a bunch of others I'll really miss, but these are the main ones I use all the time.

Answer (score 1):

about the go to symbol thing

there are the following functionalities available

<kbd>ctrl + shift + r</kbd> - open resource

<kbd>ctrl + shift + t</kbd> - open type

<kbd>ctrl + alt + g</kbd> - find the selected text in workspace

<kbd>ctrl + shift + g</kbd> - find references in workplace (as selected by caret)

<kbd>ctrl + o</kbd>  - quick outline, all methods in class

there is also a plugin calld [instaSearch](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/instasearch) that you can easily install, it offers a complete project active search.

Answer (score 0):

I believe IntelliJ is a much better IDEA, but you asked..

<kbd>ctrl+w</kbd>
<kbd>Alt Shift Up</kbd>     Expand selection to enclosing element

<kbd>ctrl+d</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl Alt Arrow</kbd>   Duplicate line(s) up or down

<kbd>ctrl+shift+v</kbd>
Not that I have seen

<kbd>ctrl+shift+a</kbd>
No, and that is a truly amazing feature.